# skimage.transform: warp() got an unexpected keyword argument 'preserve_range'

Tags: conv-neural-network, scikit-image

I am running a CNN program for medical images which also includes data augmentation by randomly transforming given images. In data augmentation part, I am facing this error. Please help me out.
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue with older version of python skimage. On updating python skimage, this issue will not be anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you. Try to install the bleeding edge version of Theano.

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```